# mysql count related table

Tags: mysql, join, count

Hi everyone I would like to count some entries, but I don't know if is possible to do it with joins. The situation is

I've got a tables

**student_profile**

```
Id | Name
---------
1  | Name1
2  | Name2 
3  | Name3
```

**student_application** where profile_id is related to student_profile.id

```
     Id | profile_id | Data
     ----------------------
     1      2          data1
     2      2          data2
     3      2          data3
```

And table **student_holiday**

```
Id | app_id | date
-----------------------
1      2      2014-01-01
2      3      2014-02-02
```

So I'm getting all my `student_application`'s with

```
Select sa.id, s.name From student_application sa 
INNER JOIN student_profile s ON s.id =  sa.profile_id
```

I would like to count how many holidays has a student, but I don't have profile_id in student_holiday table. There I've got app_id, so I can't do Left join student_holiday sh ON sh.app_id = sa.id, this wouldn't give the right number.

here [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b76b/2)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So there is no relation between the `student_holiday` table and one of the other two?

Comment: No there is relation between student_holiday and student_application, student_holiday.app_id = student_application.id, and another one with student_profile.id = student_application.profile_id the result has to be something like this, Name2|count(2), Name2|count(2), Name2|count(2), 3 times because I've got 3 applications for that student and this profile has 2 holidays, I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT student_profile.ID, student_profile.Name, student_holiday.ID
FROM (student_profile INNER JOIN student_holiday ON student_profile.ID = student_holiday.ID) INNER JOIN student_application ON student_holiday.ID = student_application.ID;
```

Here you go!!! Match ID in all the table as instructed above which is the key to get holidays.

OR match with profile_id

```
**SELECT student_profile.ID, student_profile.Name, student_holiday.ID
FROM (student_profile INNER JOIN student_holiday ON student_profile.ID = student_holiday.ID) INNER JOIN student_application ON Trim(student_holiday.ID) = 
student_application.profile_id;**
```

Comment: He provided a sqlfiddle, all you have to do is plug these solutions into it to see that they don't work

Comment: These queries don't work.  I would strongly suggest refraining from answering questions since you consistently seem to be just guessing and not testing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your data with the 3rd table joined:

```
Select s.name, sa.some_data as application_data,h.some_data as holiday_data 
From student_application sa
INNER JOIN student_profile s ON s.id = sa.profile_id
INNER JOIN student_holiday h  ON h.app_id = sa.id;
```

Note this will only return records that have an application with a holiday associated.

Then to count them, we just:

```
Select s.name, sa.some_data as application_data,count(h.some_data) as holiday_data 
From student_application sa
INNER JOIN student_profile s ON s.id = sa.profile_id
INNER JOIN student_holiday h  ON h.app_id = sa.id
GROUP BY s.name
```

Note this answer is based on the fieldnames you used in your sqlfiddle (Data = some_data and date = some_data)